# How do I write a URL in Markdown on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, markdown

If I want to write the URL of a website on Stack Exchange using Markdown, how do I do that?

For example:

```
<a href="abc.php">ABC</a>
```

What is the way to write this URL on Stack Exchange?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help (and note that new users can only add one —or even zero?— link to a post).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Actually, *Markdown* supports three (plus one) ways of creating a clickable link.

```
1. [Stack Overflow][1] (number reference)
2. [Stack Overflow][so] (tagged reference)
3. [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) (direct reference)

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com
[so]: http://stackoverflow.com
```

Results in:

1. [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) (number reference)
2. [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) (tagged reference)
3. [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) (direct reference)

And, of course, a raw URL will be converted to be clickable.

```
http://stackoverflow.com
```

Results in:

http://stackoverflow.com

This is all in [the Help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links), of course. Don't be afraid to click that little question mark above the text area.

Comment: Turns out to be [four plus one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68034/147640).

Comment: And also by using `<` and `>`, like this: `<http://example.com>`

Answer (score 2):

In stack overflow, you can make links by following the steps:

- Link text is enclosed in square brackets eq: [ABC]
- Next you provide a link number beside it eq: [ABC] [x]
- At the bottom of your post you provide the actual link in the form:  [x]: link URL

so your content will look like:

```
[ABC][1]
```

And the bottom of the post you will have:

```
[1]: http://your-actual-link.com
```

Comment: Or: use the toolbar above the editor, or press Ctrl-L.